# How to modify tomcat server.xml to run on port 8443 with self-signed certificate in docker

Tags: docker, tomcat, dockerfile

I am following this Link to create self-signed certificate: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

I need to do this using docker but, its telling me to modify the tomcat server.xml file on some path that doesnt exist. Again, as far as I understand there is no point in me making these changes locally. I need to make the changes either in dockerfile or the dockerStartup.sh file I think. Could someone please provide me with some guidance. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain further on what step you have an issue, what you have tried and maybe post some of your configuration (your Dockerfile and command lines could be a good start) ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to mount your modified file as a volume when running the container, for example:

```
docker run -d -v ./server.xml:/path/to/my/config/on/the/container/server.xml --name my_tomcat_server myimagename
```

With that, the server will read the modified config file, as long as you mount it in the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the server.xml externally from a Volume , also the self signed or for that matter any external certificates needs to be mounted from a volume to the internal desired path of the container.

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:7080 \
-v /${HOST_PATH}/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps \
-v /${HOST_PATH}/server.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml \
tomcat:8.0
```