# In tomcat9 should server.xml define an https (8443) using SSLHostConfig and Certificate elements or properties?

Tags: tomcat

I'm trying to configure tomcat9 to support HTTPS on port 8443.

It appears that there is conflicting information on how to configure HTTPS in tomcat 9.

1. The downloaded conf/server.xml file shows configuration one way,
2. The documentation explains how to do it using a different syntax.

So in tomcat9 should server.xml define an https (8443) using `<SSLHostConfig>` and `<Certificate>` elements or properties on the `<Connector/>` element?

### Details

I downloaded tomcat 9.0.73  from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi.

The provided `conf/server.xml` file contains the syntax:

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

Notice the `<SSLHostConfig>` and `<Certificate/>` elements are used.

The Tomcat 9 documentation [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File) says:

> The final step is to configure the Connector in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml file, where $CATALINA_BASE represents the base directory for the Tomcat instance. An example  element for an SSL connector is included in the default server.xml file installed with Tomcat. To configure an SSL connector that uses JSSE, you will need to remove the comments and edit it so it looks something like this:

```
<!-- Define an SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

NOTE: There is no mention of `<SSLHostConfig>` or `<Certificate>` elements.

**My question is: Which way is the right way to configure https?**

## Searching for an answer gave me these

- [How to modify tomcat server.xml to run on port 8443 with self-signed certificate in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57872460/how-to-modify-tomcat-server-xml-to-run-on-port-8443-with-self-signed-certificate) - Uses tomcat 7
- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File
- Documentation for properties supported on `<SSLHostConfig>` element. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_SSLHostConfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them are correct and can work.

I successfully used both approaches with different syntax and both worked.  The key is getting the right properties on each element.

I'll show each of them.

### Solution using properties on Connection

The following shows the configuration when using properties on the `<Connector>` element.

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
        sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
        acceptCount="100"
        sslProtocol="TLS"
        clientAuth="want"
        enableLookups="true"
        keystoreFile="/.../.../mykeystore.jks"
        keystorePass="changeit" (default)
        keystoreType="JKS"
        truststoreFile=".../.../truststore.jks"
        truststorePass="changeit" (default)
        truststoreType="JKS"
        maxPostSize="2097152"
        scheme="https"
        disableUploadTimeout="true"
        minSpareThreads="10"
        secure="true"
        URIEncoding="UTF-8"
        maxKeepAliveRequests="150"
    />
```

There are more properties than is needed but I didn't want to take the time to find the minimal set (for this post).

The passwords shown `changeit` are the defaults used by Java if these fields are not present.  I choose to include them to make it easier for someone else to copy/paste this and use it (as they would need to set the password to match their configuration).

### Solution using  and

The syntax using `<SSLHostConfig>` and `<Certificate>` elements is shown next.

I took the above and morphed it into this syntax until it worked.

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
               acceptCount="100"
    >
        <SSLHostConfig 
            certificateVerification="required"
            protocols="+TLSv1.1,+TLSv1.2"
            truststoreFile="/.../.../truststore.jks"
            truststorePassword="changeit"
            truststoreType="JKS"
            >
            <Certificate 
                certificateKeystoreFile="/.../.../mykeystore.jks" 
                type="RSA" 
                certificateKeystorePassword="changeit"
            />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

#### Summary

The configuration for tomcat can use a properties or elements to configure an SSL connector.

When tomcat configures the connector, it will automatically create an `<SSLHostConfig>` for the `_default_` hostName so internally the `SSLHostConfig` is used.

If you try to mix and match, you'll get an error saying that a default hostName already is created so the configuration fails.

The exact error looked like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple SSLHostConfig elements were provided for the host name [_default_]. Host names must be unique.
```

The links in this post earlier were valid and are summarized next.

- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html - Start here...

  - [Edit the Tomcat Configuration File](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File)
- Docs for `<SSLHostConfig>` [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_Connector_-_NIO_and_NIO2)

Comment: The use of `<SSLHostConfig>` is preferred because it gives you more control over all of the various TLS configurations. There are configurations that are only possible when using `<SSLHostConfig>` and not possible otherwise.